# A $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}$ and $e^{i \frac{\pi}{5}}$ such that $A^n = I$. Find the smallest possible value of $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> A $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $e^{i \frac{\pi}{4}}$ and $e^{i \frac{\pi}{5}}$ such that $A^n = I$. Find the smallest possible value of $n$.

---

How to find the smallest value of $n$?

Comment: Hint: $A=P\begin{bmatrix}e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}&0\\0&e^{\frac{i\pi}{5}}\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$, then $A^n=(PDP^{-1})^n=.....$.

Comment: Can you please show me the exact steps? I'm unable to solve this.

Comment: Are you familiar with diagonalization? If yes then the second hint is $A^n=(PDP^{-1}) \, (PDP^{-1}) \, (PDP^{-1}) \dotsb (PDP^{-1})=PD^nP^{-1}$. You want this to be $I$, so..

Comment: Can n be negative?

Answer (score 0):

Setting $\lambda_1 = e^{\frac{i \pi}{4}}$ and $\lambda_2 = e^{\frac{i \pi}{5}}$, we see that $A^n$ is $I$ iff $\lambda_1^n = 1 = \lambda_2^n$. This follows from $$A^n = \left(P\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0\\0 & \lambda_2\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}\right)^n = P\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1^n & 0\\0 & \lambda_2^n\end{bmatrix}P^{-1}$$ where $P$ is the change of base matrix (which we have as we have a 2 by 2 matrix with two distinct eigenvalues)

It's clear that $\lambda_1^n =1$ iff $n$ is a multiple of $8$ (its order in $\Bbb C^\ast$ is $8$, and likewise for $\lambda_2$ and multiples of $10$).

So we're looking for the smallest $n$ that is both a multiple of $8$ and $10$..

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues of $A^n$ are the $n$-th powers of the eigenvalues of $A$ : $e^{i n\frac{\pi}{4}}$ and $e^{i n\frac{\pi}{5}}$.

The objective is to find $n$ such that these eigenvalues are the eigenvalues of $I$, i.e., $1=e^{i k 2 \pi}$, which means the equality of exponents :

$$n\frac{\pi}{4}=k 2 \pi \ \ \text{and} \ \ n\frac{\pi}{5}=k' 2 \pi$$

for certain $k,k' \in \mathbb{Z}$

otherwise said :

$$n=k 8\ \ \text{and} \ \ n=k' 10$$

Conclusion :

$$n=\text{lcm}(8,10)=40$$